# JetBrains WebStorm auto format conflict with ESLint rule no-case-declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, eslint

When setting up ESLint for my project I found that the auto format feature of JetBrains IDE's conflict with the ESLint rule 'no-case-declarations'.

The problem is that JetBrains' IDE formats a switch statement such that the block is (non-indented) on a newline which is unwanted behavior but I cannot find a option to turn this behaviour off.

For example, when reformatting this code

```
switch(test){
  case 1: {
    let bla = getBlaForTest(test);
  }
}
```

It will be auto formatted to

```
switch(test){
  case 1: 
  {
    let bla = getBlaForTest(test);
  }
}
```

Which gives an ESLint error that the indenting is wrong (which it is in my opinion).

Does anyone know if this is a limitation of WebStorm or if there is a more advanced way to manage the auto format rules?

Comment: Why do you use braces in case?

Comment: You should decide: auto formatting with webstorm or hard work (also high quality) with ESLint.

Comment: @Everettss Nonsense. Adjust the tools to support you instead.

Comment: @str maybe I underestimate auto formatting tools. You mean this by: "click on autoformat button and IDE mess with your code to format it with unknowing rules"?

Comment: Also you can change the place of the braces: Settings->Editor->Code Style->JavaScript->Wrapping and Braces->Braces placement->Other->End of line

Comment: @Ziki Because, since `let` and `const` are block scoped you cannot use the same variable name in multiple `case` statements without the extra block. More info can be read in the [ESLint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-case-declarations)

Comment: @Ziki Thanks for the suggestion but that option is already set to 'End of line'. I've exported my code style config to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/BasKiers/47dd93160c12bf465f4cbd5924e1d3da)

Comment: @Bas When I use your code style, the result is the same as you expected. Also when I change the value of the setting that I wrote above it's change.

Comment: @Everettss No I mean "configure it the way you like and stop worrying about it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour [is fixed already](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21149) and fix will be available in WebStorm **2016.2**.

You can try WebStorm **2016.2 EAP build** right now -- http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-232/

Comment: Nice! that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Bas Good to know. It works for me probably because I use: WebStorm 2016.2 EAP Build 162.232.15